# Is the functor associating a bundle with a structure group to a principal bundle faithful?

Tags: general-topology

Consider a (Cartan) principal G-bundle $\xi: X \to B$, and a left $G$-space $F$. We construct the bundle $\xi[F]: X_F \to B$ associated with $\xi$ with a fiber $F$ as usual. Now for each morphism $(u, f)$ between principal bundles $\xi: X \to A$ and $\eta: Y \to B$ we can associate a morphism $(u_F, f): \xi[F] \to \eta[F]$, where $u_F((x, y)G) = (u(x), y)G$. Thus we can construct a functor from the category of principal $G$-bundles to some (not full) subcategory of the category of bundles ($\mathbf{Top}^\to$), which we call the category of bundles with the structure group $G$ and the fiber $F$.

*Is this functor faithful?*

For any two morphisms $(u, f), (v, f): \xi \to \eta$ $u_F = v_F$ is equivalent to the identity $\{(u(x)s, s^{-1}y) \mid s \in G\} = \{(v(x)s, s^{-1}y \mid s \in G\}$ for any $x \in X$ and for any $y \in F$. In particular, this implies that $u(x) G_y = v(x) G_y$, where $G_y$ is the stabilizer of $y \in F$, so if $G_y = 1$ for some $y \in F$, then the functor is faithful.

Is this correct? I am not comfortable with this argument because of the massive amount of quotients and factorizations involved in construction of associated bundles, *can someone please check if I'm missing something?*

Also, while the action of $GL_n(\mathbb{R})$ on $\mathbb{R}^n$ is faithful, every vector has a non-trivial stabilizer. *Is the functor in question faithful in case of vector bundles?*

**If I need to clarify something or ask a more concrete question, please inform me in the comments.**

Comment: What's a free functor? If you mean it's the left adjoint of some forgetful functor, say that instead.

Comment: @ZhenLin: I meant faithful, sorry :)

Comment: What if $F$ is a point?

Comment: @AkhilMathew: then for any trivial principal bundle $\pi_B: G \times B \to B$ any non-trivial automorphism of $G$ induces the identity automorphism on $\pi_B[*]$. But then the stabilizer of any $y \in *$ is the whole $G$ so the functor in question is only faithful when $G = 1$.